# split values in dictionary in separate values

Tags: python

I have this type of string:

```
sheet = """
magenta
turquoise,PF00575
tan,PF00154,PF06745,PF08423,PF13481,PF14520
turquoise, PF00011
NULL
"""
```

Every line starts with an identifier (e.g. tan, magenta...) What I want is to count the number of occurrences of each PF-number per identifier.

So, the final structure would be something like this:

```
         magenta  turquoise tan NULL
PF00575   0          0       0   0
PF00154   0          1       0   0
PF06745   0          0       1   0
PF08423   0          0       1   0
PF13481   0          0       1   0
PF14520   0          0       1   0
PF00011   0          1       0   0
```

I started with making a a dictionary where every first word on a line is a key and then I want as values the PF-numbers behind it.

When I use this code, I get the values as a list of strings instead of as separate values in the dictionary:

```
lines = []
lines.append(sheet.split("\n"))
flattened=[]
flattened = [val for sublist in lines for val in sublist]
pfams = []
for i in flattened:
    pfams.append(i.split(","))
d = defaultdict(list)
for i in pfams:
pfam = i[0]
d[pfam].append(i[1:])
```

So, the result is this:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'': [[], []], 'magenta': [[]], 'NULL': [[]], 'turquoise': [['PF00575']], 'tan': [['PF00154', 'PF06745', 'PF08423', 'PF13481', 'PF14520']]})
```

How can I split up the PFnumbers so that they are separate values in the dictionary and then count the number of occurrences of each unique PF-number per key?

Comment: Start by showing what you want your `final` data to look like (assuming everything works as expected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to dwblas on devshed, this is the most efficient way I've found to tackle the task:

I build a dictionary whose key is the PFnumber, and a list ordered by how I want the colors printed.

```
colors_list= ['cyan','darkorange','greenyellow','yellow','magenta','blue','green','midnightblue','brown','darkred','lightcyan','lightgreen','darkgreen','royalblue','orange','purple','tan','grey60','darkturquoise','red','lightyellow','darkgrey','turquoise','salmon','black','pink','grey','null']
lines = sheet.splitlines()
counts = {}

for line in lines:
    parts = line.split(",")
    if len(parts) > 1:
        ## doesn't break out the same item in the list many times
        color=parts[0].strip().lower()
        for key in parts[1:]:  ## skip color
            key=key.strip()
            if key not in counts:
                ## new key and list of zeroes-print it if you want to verify
                counts[key]=[0 for ctr in range(len(colors_list))]

            ## offset number/location of this color in list
            el_number=colors_list.index(color)
            if color > -1:  ## color found
                counts[key][el_number] += 1
            else:
                print "some error message"

import csv

with open("out.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer=csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow( ["PFAM",] + colors_list)
    for pfam in counts:
    writer.writerow([pfam] + counts[pfam])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `collections.Counter` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
import collections

sheet = """
magenta
turquoise,PF00575
tan,PF00154,PF06745,PF08423,PF13481,PF14520
NULL
"""

acc = {}
for line in sheet.split('\n'):
    if line == "NULL":
         continue
    parts = line.split(',')
    acc[parts[0]] = collections.Counter(parts[1])
```

**EDIT:** Now with accumulating all PF values for each key

```
acc = collections.defaultdict(list)
for line in sheet.split('\n'):
    if line == "NULL":
         continue
    parts = line.split(',')
    acc[parts[0]] += parts[1:]
acc = {k: collections.Counter(v) for k,v in acc.iteritems()}
```

**Final edit** Count the occurrence of colours per PF value, which is what we were after all along, in the end:

```
acc = collections.defaultdict(list)
for line in sheet.split('\n'):
    if line == "NULL":
         continue
    parts = line.split(',')
    for pfval in parts[1:]
         acc[ pfval ] += [ parts[0] ]
acc = {k: collections.Counter(v) for k,v in acc.iteritems()}
```

Comment: Thanks.I adjusted your code to this `acc = {}
for line in sheet.split('\n'):
    parts = line.split(',')
    if len(parts) > 1:
        acc[parts[0]] = collections.Counter(parts[1].split(","))` 
The issue is that it only counts the last occurrence of each key. So I need to build the dictionary first based on every line because the keys occur more than once. Make sense? Thanks !

Comment: That would be one way; if you want to aggregate the PF values for all occurrences of the same key you could first aggregate all the PF values per key and then finally put them through the Counter.

Comment: I'm trying that, but doesn't work. Could you give it a try and change your answer?

Comment: I get a key error after `acc[parts[0]] += parts[1:]`. It says `KeyError: 'magenta'` Do you know why that is?

Comment: Hang on, you want to count it different. Per PF value you want to count how often they are used in each colour (first word on the line)

Comment: You forgot to make `acc`  a `collections.defaultdict(list)`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72957/discussion-between-oaklander114-and-haavee).